# How can I connect two Apps using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have an app in the App Store that uses Firebase. I have begun working on another app that I am putting in the same group on Frebase's dashboard.

My goal is that when this is up and running a user will be able to connect both accounts and data can then be shared with both. For example if on app #1 a user says Item A = 25, then on app #2 they can see that and interact with it (the connection could go both ways).

**Potentially Flawed Idea**

The solution was if they use the same login credentials then this would just be automatically handled. However, if the user is unaware of my other app and for whatever reason logs in with another email I would be stuck.

Even if I

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried create a firebase project with 2 mobile app connected to it? I have already implemented this kind of thing. Feel free to ask.

Comment: This is my first time doing so